# How to create empty time plot frame with nicely formatted tickmarks

Tags: r, plot

If I do a straight plot like below, I get nice x-axis tick labels indicating January, February, etc.

```
plot(y=c(0, 10), x=c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31")))
```

[image]

How do I get the same behavior, but with an empty plot frame?  Why doesn't below work? I get tick marks that are numerically labeled, not pretty-labeled with the month.

```
plot(0, xlim=c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31")), ylim=c(0, 10), type="n")
```

[image]

Comment: `plot(y=0, x=as.Date("2013-1-1"), xlim=c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31")), ylim=c(0, 10), type="n")` might preserve dates on the x-axis.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Including a date x value convinces plot to use pretty formatting. Post as an answ and I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot(y=0, x=as.Date("2013-1-1"), xlim=c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31")), ylim=c(0, 10), type="n")` might preserve dates on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You just want `type = "n"` in the `plot()` call:

```
plot(y=c(0, 10), x=c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31")), type = "n")
```

The `"n"` means plot nothing.

The reason your second attempt:

```
plot(0, xlim=c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31")), ylim=c(0, 10),
     type="n")
```

doesn't work is that the underlying plotting code treats the Date objects you passed as the `xlim` argument as numerics (the number of days since the epoch is how the `"Date"` class is defined, and stored internally as a numeric). We can see roughtly what is happening if we do:

```
> pretty(as.numeric(c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-12-31"))))
[1] 15700 15800 15900 16000 16100
```